# Expand Parent Container Only As Wide as Children Max-Widths

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a parent container with `flex-direction: row` and several child elements with a `max-width`. I'm trying to get the parent to expand as wide as the child elements under their max widths but no wider.

```css
parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

child {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div className={parent}>
  <div className={child}>Child 1</div>
  <div className={child}>Child 2</div>
  <div className={child}>Child 3</div>
</div>
```

This expands the parent across the available view, which I don't want because it's push over another element I have in an adjacent column, creating an awkward gap.

But if I change the width to something like `fit-content`, it collapses the child elements smaller than their max widths.

How do I make the parent container as wide as the child max-widths, but no wider (while also being able to shrink the child elements if the window size condenses).

Comment: .parent {
            display: inline-flex;
 }

Answer (score 1):

You should use  `display: inline-flex` and remove `width:100%` from parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("[type=range]").change(function () {
   const width = $(this).val();
    $('.child').css('width',width+"px")
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border:3px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.child {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
</div>

<div class="range-container">
  <input type="range" id="points" name="points" min="50" max="200">
</div>
```